# How to measure output voltage and current of a VFD?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, vfd

Is it possible to measure the output of a Variable Frequency Drive without relying on it's display data? I tried to measure the line voltage with a DMM and current with a clamp meter but it shows inaccurate results. I'm running the motor at 50Hz and the carrier frequency is 6kHz if that matters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so easily. It's a really "dirty" signal if you look at it on an oscilloscope. You would need something like a power meter with fairly wide bandwidth, and to measure both current and voltage together (ie. simultaneous samples at a high sample rate, likely with anti-aliasing) and the meter would have to multiply and integrate the result .

Such meters certainly exist, but maybe they are not so affordable.

Answer (score 0):

Most VFDs can provide analog output signals that are proportional to output current and speed. Output voltage is approximately proportional to speed. The VFD may also be able to provide a signal that is proportional to torque. The VFD signals will be more accurate than any measurement that you can do easily and inexpensively.

If you have a specific reason for wanting the measurements, it might to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sometimes I'm experiencing a voltage drop at high loads (within the limit of course) and the VFD trips showing under-voltage fault. When I measure the input from the mains at such loads it never drops below 210V so I wanted to check the output without trusting the VFD but it looks like I don't have many options on that one. Anyways I will be opening a new question/topic regarding this issue so we don't expand here.